# Paint images on JPanel from another class

Tags: java, swing

I am making a roundabout simulation. The images are all painted in `doDrawing()` so far, but the program is connected with a server so I want to draw (spawn) the images from another class according to what the server sends. For testing purposes I identify a `byte` array on `mousePressed()` in the `Roundabout` class. This works I can see the `println` from `spawnPedestrian()` but the pedestrian isn't painted on the `JPanel`.

What do I have to change in `spawnPedestrian()` to make it work?

Roundabout.java - main class

```
public class Roundabout extends JFrame{

Track track=new Track();
TrafficLight trafficLight1=new TrafficLight(1);
TrafficLight trafficLight3=new TrafficLight(3);
TrafficLight trafficLight2=new TrafficLight(2);
TrafficLight trafficLight4=new TrafficLight(4);
TrafficLight trafficLight5=new TrafficLight(5);
Car car=new Car(412, 750); // south to west
Car car2=new Car(50,400); // west to south
Car car3=new Car(700,290); //east to south
Car car4=new Car(470,750);
Bus bus=new Bus();
Bicycle bicycle=new Bicycle();
Pedestrian pedestrian = new Pedestrian(571,750);
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
//public ArrayList<TrafficLight> trafficLights = new ArrayList<>{trafficLight3}();

public static Map<Integer,TrafficLight> trafficLights = new HashMap<>();

byte[] array=new byte[]{0,2,1,1}; //test byte array

private Long startTime;
private long playTime = 4000;
private double i;

static TCPClient client;

Surface surface=new Surface();

class Surface extends JPanel {

private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

    Dimension size = getSize();
    Insets insets = getInsets();

    int w = size.width - insets.left - insets.right;
    int h = size.height - insets.top - insets.bottom;

    /* Draw the track first */
    track.paint(g);

    /* Draw a car */
    //car.START_POS = new Point(412, 750);
    car.setCarLane(Lane.topLane);
    car.paint(g);
    cars.add(car); //add to list

    //car2.START_POS=new Point(50,400);
    car2.carRotation=180;
    car2.setCarLane(Lane.wsLane);
    car2.paint(g);
    cars.add(car2);

    car3.carRotation=360;
    car3.setCarLane(Lane.esLane);
    car3.paint(g);
    cars.add(car3);

    car4.setCarLane(Lane.seLane);
    car4.paint(g);
    cars.add(car4);

    /*Draw a bus*/
    bus.paint(g);

    /*Draw a bicycle */
    bicycle.setBicyclePath(Lane.bicyclePath);
    bicycle.paint(g);

    /*Draw a pedestrian */
    pedestrian.setPedestrianPath(Lane.pedesSePath);
    pedestrian.paint(g);

    /* Draw traffic light*/ 

    trafficLight1.setPosition(520, 333);
    trafficLight1.paint(g);

    trafficLight3.setPosition(100, 275);
    trafficLight3.paint(g);

    trafficLight2.setPosition(100, 400);
    trafficLight2.paint(g);

    trafficLight4.setPosition(355, 535);
    trafficLight4.paint(g);

    trafficLight5.setPosition(404, 535);
    trafficLight5.paint(g);


}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    doDrawing(g);
}
}

public Roundabout(){
    initUI();

    trafficLights.put(trafficLight1.id, trafficLight1);
    trafficLights.put(trafficLight2.id,trafficLight2);
    trafficLights.put(trafficLight3.id,trafficLight3);
    trafficLights.put(trafficLight4.id,trafficLight4);
    trafficLights.put(trafficLight5.id,trafficLight5);
}


private void initUI() {

    setTitle("Roundabout");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    add(surface);

    //add start
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {// empty implementation of all
        // MouseListener`s methods
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getX() + "," + e.getY());
            ByteProtocol proto=new ByteProtocol();
            proto.identifyByteArray(new byte []{0x01,0x02,0x01,0x00});

        }
    });
    //end add

    //setSize(580, 550);
    setSize(1618,850);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {


    //Swing thread
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Roundabout roundabout=new Roundabout();
            roundabout.setVisible(true);    
            roundabout.moveCar();       
        }
    });             

  }
}
```

ByteProtocol.java method where `spawnPedestrian()` is called.

```
public void identifyByteArray(byte [] inputArray) {

    byte identifier=inputArray[0];


    switch(identifier){
        case vehicle: 
            System.out.println("Identifier: Vehicle");
            decodeVehicleArray(inputArray);
            break;
        case trafficLight:
            System.out.println("Traffic light");
            decodeTrafficLightArray(inputArray);
            break;
        case vehicleRegistration:
            System.out.println("Vehicle registration");
            decodeVehicleRegistrationArray(inputArray);
            break;
        default: System.out.println("Unable to identify the byte array.");
            break;
    }
}

public void decodeVehicleArray(byte [] vehicleArray){

    byte startPosition=vehicleArray[1];
    String startPositionString = directions.get(startPosition);
    System.out.println("Start position: "+startPositionString);

    byte endPosition=vehicleArray[2];
    String endPositionString = directions.get(endPosition);
    System.out.println("End position: "+endPositionString);

    byte vehicleType=vehicleArray[3];
    String vehicleTypeString=vehicles.get(vehicleType);
    System.out.println("Vehicle: "+vehicleTypeString);


    Spawn spawn=new Spawn();
    spawn.spawnPedestrian();


    }
```

Spawn.java

```
public class Spawn {

Roundabout roundabout = new Roundabout();

public void spawnPedestrian(){
    Pedestrian p = new Pedestrian(30,50);

    System.out.println("Spawn me ");

    p.setVisible(true);
    roundabout.surface.add(p);
    roundabout.surface.revalidate();
    roundabout.surface.repaint();
    roundabout.revalidate();
    roundabout.repaint();

   }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

When you write `Roundabout roundabout = new Roundabout();` in your Spawn class, you are creating a **new object** of Roundabout type (a new JFrame in the end), and you don't want a new object of that type, you want the one which is already created.

What you need to do is reference the `JPanel` surface from the Spawn class through a getter. So add this method to Roundabout class and call it from Spawn to get its context and be able to draw on it:

```
public static JPanel getSurface()
{
    return surface;
}
```

And then in your Spawn class remove `Roundabout roundabout = new Roundabout();`, get the Surface `JPanel` object and draw on it:

```
public class Spawn {

    public void spawnPedestrian(){
    Pedestrian p = new Pedestrian(30,50);

    System.out.println("Spawn me ");

    p.setVisible(true);
    Roundabout.getSurface.add(p);
    Roundabout.getSurface.revalidate();
    Roundabout.getSurface.repaint();
    Roundabout.getSurface.revalidate();
    Roundabout.getSurface.repaint();
   }
}
```

Note that you will need to make the JPanel Surface object static.

Comment: If make `surface` static I get errors in `initUI` because this method is not static. And if I remove `Roundabout roundabout = new Roundabout();` how would I paint the JFrame?

Comment: @Sybren You get errors in `initUI()` because you are trying to reference a static object from a non static context, so you have to make your `initUI()` method also static. The point is that you don't need a new object of Roundabout type since you already have another one created. If you make another `JFrame` you won't draw on the main.

Comment: I made `roundabout` static and the getter for the panel looks like this: `public JPanel getSurface() {
        return surface;
    }
    ` and in `spawnPedestrian()` I do `Roundabout.roundabout.getSurface()` to access the JPanel but nothing is painted.

Comment: @Sybren You don't need to make Roundabout static, just Surface.

Comment: I do this `Roundabout roundabout=new Roundabout();` because otherwise I can't call `setVisible()` and `moveCar()`which are non static methods. And if I make 'initUI()'  static I get errors for `setTitle()`,`setDefaultCloseOperation()` etc because they are non static methods

Comment: @Sybren If you are having all of those problems I think you have to redesign your application in order to be able to do what you want, but that's up to you.

Comment: Redesign how? Why isn't it possible?

Comment: It is actually possible, but I don't know your plans, I don't know your project or what does it do, so you are the only one who has to think about it and the better way to do it, that's why I said that you should redesign your app.

Comment: At the moment I only want to know how I can draw on the panel from another class this must be possible but how? Maybe I do some redesigning later

Comment: As I told you, you'll have to redesign it. It's is totally possible to do what you want. The only thing you need to do is to be able to reference the `JFrame` or `JPanel` (whichever is the component in which you want to draw) from the other class, and the only way to do this is through a getter method. And said that, if you don't want to create another new `JFrame` object in the other class (which is totally useless and unnecesary), the JPanel has to be static since you are handling the main Roundabout object from the main method.